# Resize view on tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a UIView as a panel for drawing a signature and I've came up with a bit of code to expand and contract the panel when tapped. It seems to work well enough but the code seems really clumsy and I was wondering if there's perhaps a better way to achieve this.

I added a tap gesture recogniser to the view, hooked it up and have this in my `.m`:

```
BOOL clientSigLarge;

- (IBAction)handleSigTap:(id)sender
{
    CGRect frame = self.clientSigView.frame;

    if (clientSigLarge)
    {
        frame.size.height -= 400;
        frame.size.width -= 350;
        frame.origin.x += 350;
        frame.origin.y += 400;
        self.clientSigView.frame = frame;
        clientSigLarge = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        frame.size.height += 400;
        frame.size.width += 350;
        frame.origin.x -= 350;
        frame.origin.y -= 400;
        self.clientSigView.frame = frame;
        clientSigLarge = YES;
    }
}
```

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it smoother, use animation block and if your scaling-proportion is fixed (like 2x, 3x, etc.) then use CGAffineTransformScale

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 1
                      delay: 0
                    options: (UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                 animations:^{myView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, xScaleValue, yScaleVale);}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) { }
];
```

So in if-else condition just change X and Y scale values and use the same block.

Here is a reference link for [animations](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5478/uiview-animation-tutorial-practical-recipes)

Hope this is what you are looking for